# Monte Carlo Simulation (or bootstrapping ) mutually exclusive events

Tags: monte-carlo

Say event A probability of happening in a day is 1%; event B probability of happening in a day is 5%. Assuming they are independent, if I want to build a simulation model to simulate 1000 days, and each path could have multiple occurrences(1 occur, 2 not occur) of A and B. What's the best way to build this simulation model and how many simulation is ideal?

More advanced, if A and B are mutually exclusive, how the model would be like?

Comment: **(1)** Roll 2 dice. Indep: A = Less than 3 on first, B = More than 3 on second: In R: `d1 = sample(1:6, 10^6, rep=T); d2 = sample(1:6, 10^6, rep=T); a = (d1 < 3);  b = (d2 > 3);  int = (a & b);  mean(a); mean(b); mean(int)`. Return about 1/3, 1/2, 1/6. **(2)** Disjoint: D = More than 3 on first: `d = (d1 > 3)`. Look at `mean(a | d)`. // Why do you say 'disjoint' is more advanced? // For both, to get 5% and 1%,  you'd need to roll a 100 sided-die. // You could say that all bootstrapping is Monte Carlo, but not that all Monte Carlo is bootstrapping. Terms not equivalent.

Comment: It is unclear _why_ you would need a simulation for when you know exactly the probability of the different events.